# Extracting a line after a specific line in python

Tags: python, database, line, extract

I have this problem, am trying to extract two lines A and B. But i  will extract those line if B comes after A, other wise, i want to pass.  Initially, i thought they were equal amount to  i used the code,  below. It's actually part of a larger code, but this is where is issue is mainly.

```
def get_line(file_name, find_word1, find_word2):

    lines = []
    for line in file_name.strip().split('\n'):
        if find_word1 in line:
            lines.append(line)
        elif find_word2 in line:
            lines.append(line)
        else:
            pass
    return lines
```

like `find_word1` is `A` and `find_word2` is `B`.
from my code, i know i can only get  two line but not condition . I don't know how to go about this. if you can help, please kindly do
Thank you

Comment: As you do it now, you check for the two words in the same line. If I understand you correctly, are you looking for a conditional check in two consecutive lines?

Comment: yes, such that i will append the two lines if the condition occurs

Comment: and as such, the number total number we will always have will be even. in total.

Comment: why did you delete your answer

Comment: I felt like my answer did not solve your problem and based on your provided information I did not know what to do differently. If no one else solves this for you., edit this question or make a new one where you explain exactly what is not working and provide example input to the function (as I did with the main().)

Comment: probably that's what i will do at last, just that the code is pretty long

Comment: Minimize it. We only need the input. Remember the guideline "Minimal Verifiable Example" https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1X63wHmIEpWcaA5ZnMhh8RNnslitohU6G

Comment: you can check my full code there and just create some random file in the arguement, but i think someone got it already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_line(file_name, find_word1, find_word2):
    lines = []
    temp = ""

    for line in file_name.strip().split('\n'):
        if find_word1 in line and not temp:
            temp = line
        elif find_word2 in line and temp:
                lines.append(temp)
                lines.append(line)
                temp = ""
        else:
            pass

    return lines
```

Comment: Hmm, that will accept all of these combinations (A A), (A B), (B A), (B B), not what is asked (A B).

Comment: am still getting the same result as before,  i expect the total output to be even in number, since am extracting two two, but am still getting some odd output

Comment: If there are two lines containing word1 and a single line containing word2 what would be the result?

Comment: also if both words were found on a single line what would the result be?

Comment: if there are two line containing word one, take the last one closest to word two and ignore the first one,

Comment: if both words were found on a single line, that's non existent in the code

Comment: two line containing word one is very possible,  and that's why i  am having the problem since

Comment: because you said line = [lines]

Comment: one last question... if it finds the first word then the second word then again the first word what would it return?

Comment: if it finds the first word, then the second word, it returns both words, it will not append a line that does not contain the second word, after the first word.

Comment: so first word, then second word then first word then second word and so on... and it will skip if there is first word, first word until second word it found

Comment: what about now?

Comment: its returning nothing

Comment: forgot to change the last line

Comment: so i should try now ?

Comment: yeah... working now, can you now kindly explain  to me.. This has been a long conversation  Thanks

Comment: still waiting for the explanation, thanks for your help

Comment: When the loop starts the `temp` variable is empty. then as the loop goes if `find_word1` was found then temp will catch the value of that line but it will not update `lines`. then it will loop until `find_word2` is found. it will not update `temp` if `find_word1` is found because it is checking if `temp` is empty. then when it gets `find_word2` it will append both lines and reset `temp`. it goes on like this untill it finishes the loop and return `lines`. did that make sense?

Comment: This will also accept (A  X B) where X is any intermediary line. Fix it by clearing temp in the else too, so that if none of the arguments fits, the temp is forgotten.

Comment: yeah.. it makes sense now thank alot you guys, you've really helped me

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_line(file_name, find_word1, find_word2):
    lines = []
    firstWord = False
    for line in file_name.strip().split('\n'):
        if find_word1 in line and not firstWord:
            firstWord = True
            temp = line
        elif find_word2 in line and firstWord:
            lines.append(temp)
            lines.append(line)
            firstWord = False
            temp = ""
    return lines
```

You need to do an initial check for A and only if A is found do you care about B.  Otherwise B doesn't matter.  This is achieved by check if A is in that line and has not been found yet.  Once A is found a boolean can be used to mark that it was found and from that point only look for B.

Comment: I create a boolean, firstWord that I set to false.  This will be used as a flag that tells the program if the first word has been found.  From there the first check I do on a line if a multipart check. Before the "and" I look for find_word1 in line but I only care about word1 if it hasn't been found yet.  Once word1 is found I set the flag, "firstWord", to true. and temporarily hold the line so it can be printed only if word2 is found.  the second check, elif, looks for word2 in the line only if the firstWord has been found.  If both word2 is found AND firstWord has been found then both print

Comment: oh, actually its working, but its changing the final result, cuz am calcuation the difference between the two lines, and am getting an abstract result

Comment: What do you mean by calculating the difference between the two lines?  Can you post code?

Comment: you can just create a random file arrording to the arguement

Comment: So you are finding the difference between other information in the line aside from what words you search for in get_line?

Comment: yeah, i extract out the time, then find the difference in the time,

Comment: Okay.  Do you know what about the final result is wrong specifically?

Comment: Given the new information I have updated get_line so that it will keep searching for the sets of words and appending them.